# Position absolute não está a funcionar

Tags: html, css

Estou a tentar criar uma versão do antigo site da record. O que eu preciso é meter a `div` **lidas** em baixo da `div` **ultimas**, mas elas ficam seguidas e não é isso o pretendido.

Onde diz **boas**, no ultimo topico da lista, devia aparecer atras da `div`, ou seja, devia de estar escondido lá atras em vez de estar no fundo da lista

Deixo aqui o meu código e peço desculpa pela desorganização  :

```css
body {} #main {
  margin: auto;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: white;
}
#cabeçalho {
  width: 980px;
  height: 113px;
  background-image: url("imagens/topo.png");
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
#barra {
  background-image: url("imagens/fundoMenu.jpg");
  height: 35px;
}
#barraclubes {
  background-image: url("imagens/barra_cinzenta.png");
  height: 45px;
}
.separadores {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 108px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.ulclubes {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.liclubes {
  display: inline;
}
.noticiaimagem {} .horacategoria {} .descrição {
  color: red;
  width: 278px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.descriçãopequena {
  color: gray;
  width: 278px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.hora {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.categoria {
  background-color: gray;
}
.noticia {
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 278px;
}
.social {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 278px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e3e5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 80%;
}
.margem {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.comentarios {
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("imagens/comentarios.png");
}
.descriçaopp {
  font-size: 60%;
}
#header {
  background-image: url('imagens/fundo.png');
  width: 307px;
  height: 32px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -4.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.headersimbolo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 205px;
  color: white;
}
.noticiacoluna {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.ulcoluna {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.liclicada {
  color: gray;
  margin-left: -5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline;
}
.licoluna {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#noticiacolunamenu {
  background-color: black;
  width: 307px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.barra {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.horacoluna {
  color: darkgrey;
}
#coluna {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
#ultimas {
  position: absolute;
}
#lidas {
  position: absolute;
}
}
#comentadas {
  position: absolute;
}
#votadas {
  position: absolute;
}
.categoriacoluna {
  color: darkgrey;
}
.titulo {
  display: block;
}
.ulseparadores {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
.liseparadores {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("imagens/separador.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.premium {
  background-image: url("imagens/premium.jpg");
  height: 35px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="recordcss.css" type="text/css">
  <title>:.: Jornal Record :.:</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="cabeçalho">

    </div>

    <div id="barra">
      <div class="separadores">
        <ul class="ulseparadores">
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Futebol
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Mercado
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Resultados e Classificações
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Internacional
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Modalidades
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Opinião
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Multimédia
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Jogos
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Auto
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Jogo da vida
          </li>
          <li class="liseparadores">
            Fora de campo
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="premium">



      </div>







    </div>
    <div id="barraclubes">

      <ul class="ulclubes">
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/2.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/porto.png"></img>
        </LI>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/5.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/3.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/13.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/14.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/7.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/10.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/36.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/15.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/369.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/4.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/9.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/19.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/34.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/66.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/8.png"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="liclubes">
          <img src="imagens/593.png"></img>
        </li>

      </ul>








    </div>
    <div class="noticia">
      <div class="noticiaImagem">
        <img src="imagens/noticia1.jpg"></img>
      </div>

      <div class="horacategoria">
        <span class="hora">
15:30
</span>
        <span class="categoria ">
Selecções
</span>

      </div>

      <div class="descrição">
        <h1>Nelson Oliveira:«Benfica? Se calhar cometi alguns erros»   </h1>

      </div>
      <div class="descriçãopequena">avançado comenta maior aposta nos jovens</div>
      <div class="social">
        <span class="comentarios">89</span> comentários
      </div>
      <div class="descriçaopp">
        "Não sei mas neste momento tambem não estou preocupado"
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="noticia">
      <div class="noticiaImagem">
        <img src="imagens/noticia2.jpg"></img>
      </div>

      <div class="horacategoria">
        <span class="hora">
04:35
</span>
        <span class="categoria ">
Sporting
</span>

      </div>

      <div class="descrição">
        <h1>Naldo chamado à pedra por Jesus</h1>

      </div>
      <div class="descriçãopequena">.</div>
      <div class="social">
        <span class="comentarios">8</span> comentários
      </div>
      <div class="descriçaopp">
        <ul style="background-color:gray;">
          <li>Naldo falha Benfica e tem belenences em risco
          </li>
          <li>Primeira expulsão de Naldo a jogar na Europa
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="coluna">
      <div id="header">Notícias<span class="headersimbolo">[+]</span>
      </div>
      <div id="noticiacolunamenu">
        <ul class="ulcoluna">

          <li class="liclicada">Últimas</li>

          <li class="licoluna">+ Lidas |</li>
          <li class="licoluna">+ Comentadas |</li>
          <li class="licoluna">+ Votadas</li>



        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="ultimas margem">
        <div class="conteudo">
          <div class="noticiacoluna">
            <span class="horacoluna">11:23</span>

            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Fc Porto </span>
            <span class="titulo"> Ausência de oi Martins Indi no regresso do Sérgio Oliveira</span>
          </div>

          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Selecções</span>
            <span class="titulo">Todos disponíveis antes da viagem para a Rússia</span>

          </div>
          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:11</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">RealMadrid</span>
            <span class="titulo">Carlo Ancelotti «O meu despedimento do Real Madrid não foi correcto»</span>

          </div>
          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Internacional</span>
            <span class="titulo">FIFA: Platini critica lentidão do comité de recurso</span>


          </div>
          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Vídeos-NBA</span>
            <span class="titulo">Conheces estes gestos de algum lado ...?</span>

          </div>
          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Fotos-Motociclismo</span>
            <span class="titulo">Miguel Oliveira já testa Moto2</span>

          </div>
          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Inglaterra</span>
            <span class="titulo">Carlo Ancelotti «Mourinho deu-me os parabéns quando o RealMadrid ganhou a Décima»</span>

          </div>
          <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
            <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Selecções</span>
            <span class="titulo">Nélson oliveira:«Benfica? Se calhar cometi alguns erros e não justifiquei a aposta»</span>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="lidas margem">

          <div class="noticiacoluna">
            <span class="horacoluna">11:23</span>

            <span class="barra"> | </span>
            <span class="categoriacoluna">Fc Porto </span>
            <span class="titulo"> Boassd </span>
          </div>


        </div>



      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Para o absolute funcionar em relação a uma div de fora, essa div de fora dele tem que ser :relative (nao sei se se aplica ao seu código, como você postou tudo, ainda nao consegui analisar)

Comment: era [disto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102278/11886) que estavas a precisar @TiagoCoelho ?

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei meio confuso com a questão, pois entendi duas possibilidades diferentes:

1. as `div` com `position:absolute` não possuem coordenadas, ou seja você não informou a posição em que elas devem ficar, o que faz com que elas fiquem aglutinadas. No CSS, use por exemplo `{position:absolute;top:50px;left:10%;}` para mudar a localização da `div`.
2. se uma `div` deve ficar atrás de outra, escondida, então você precisa usar a propriedade `z-index`, que muda a "camada" em que os elementos ficam. Por exemplo, um elemento com `z-index:10` fica atrás de outro com `z-index:11`, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se entendi direito, mas pelo que eu percebi, queres fazer 3 listas, cujo os botões de navegação - <kbd>Últimas</kbd>, <kbd>+ Lidas |</kbd>, <kbd>+ Comentadas |</kbd>, <kbd>+ Votadas`</kbd> do 3º 'widget' no final da página a contar da esquerda para a direita, ao serem clicados, escondam ou mostrem as respetivas listas designadas para cada botão, abaixo destes botões de navegação.

Se é isso o que estás a tentar fazer, o que estás à procura não é da posição `absolute` do CSS, mas sim de uma função em JavaScript para mostrar ou esconder `div`'s através de `display:none;` e `display:block;` quando um botão é clicado.

Aqui está um exemplo de como isto pode ser feito:

```js
// Este código JavaScript abaixo deve ser implementado antes do encerramento da tag </head>
var selecionado="news1";
var disp="feedResume1";
function show(a,b)
{
  document.getElementById(selecionado).setAttribute(
    "style", "background-color:#000; color:#fff;");
  document.getElementById(disp).style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById(a).setAttribute(
    "style", "background-color:#fff; color:#808080;");

  document.getElementById(b).style.display = "block";
  selecionado=a;
  disp=b;
}
```

```css
#feedResume2 {display: none;}
#feedResume3 {display: none;}
.resultadosFeed{
  position:relative;
  bottom:1px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:30px;
  background-color:rgb(200,200,200);
}
.ulcoluna {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
ul.ulcoluna li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
ul.ulcoluna li:first-child {
  background-color:#fff;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<div id="noticiacolunamenu">
  <ul class="ulcoluna">
    <li id='news1' onclick="show('news1','feedResume1');">Últimas</li>
    <li id='news2' onclick="show('news2','feedResume2');">Lidas</li>
    <li id='news3' onclick="show('news3','feedResume3');">Comentadas </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section id="feedResume1" class="resultadosFeed">
  <div class="conteudo">
    
    <div class="noticiacoluna">
      <span class="horacoluna">11:23</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Fc Porto </span>
      <span class="titulo"> Ausência de oi Martins Indi no regresso do Sérgio Oliveira</span>
    </div>

    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Selecções</span>
      <span class="titulo">Todos disponíveis antes da viagem para a Rússia</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:11</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">RealMadrid</span>
      <span class="titulo">Carlo Ancelotti «O meu despedimento do Real Madrid não foi correcto»</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Internacional</span>
      <span class="titulo">FIFA: Platini critica lentidão do comité de recurso</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Vídeos-NBA</span>
      <span class="titulo">Conheces estes gestos de algum lado ...?</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Fotos-Motociclismo</span>
      <span class="titulo">Miguel Oliveira já testa Moto2</span>

    </div>
    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Inglaterra</span>
      <span class="titulo">Carlo Ancelotti «Mourinho deu-me os parabéns quando o RealMadrid ganhou a Décima»</span>
    </div>

    <div class="noticiacoluna margem">
      <span class="horacoluna"> 11:39</span>
      <span class="barra"> | </span>
      <span class="categoriacoluna">Selecções</span>
      <span class="titulo">Nélson oliveira:«Benfica? Se calhar cometi alguns erros e não justifiquei a aposta»</span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>

<section id="feedResume2" class="resultadosFeed">
  <div class="noticiacoluna">
    <span class="horacoluna">11:23</span>
    <span class="barra"> | </span>
    <span class="categoriacoluna">Fc Porto </span>
    <span class="titulo"> Boassd </span>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="feedResume3" class="resultadosFeed">
</section>
```

> ### Alguns erros de sintaxe que deves ter em atenção:
>
> Em deparei-me com alguns erros de sintaxe (não verifiquei todos) que deves arranjar, como por exemplo:
>
> - Colocar 2 `id`'s num só elemento quando [deveria ser apenas 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) - `<div id="ultimas margem">`.
> - O encerramento da tag `<img>` que está assim: `<img src="imagens/2.png"></img>` quando deveria estar assim - `<img src="imagens/2.png"/>`.